# Как в aiogram3 отправить фото

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота на aiogram3, столкнулся с такой проблемой - бот не отправляет фото. Читал документацию и написал так же, но безуспешно. Этот код работает только с ссылкой на фото из интернета, а фото из папки не отправляет, писал разный путь до фото, но ошибка всегда одна и та же.

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.types import Message, FSInputFile

photo = FSInputFile("photo_2020-09-03_03-42-41.jpg")


async def menu(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption="hi")
```

Выдаёт следующую ошибку

```
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: ClientOSError: [Errno 2] Can not write request body for https://api.telegram.org/bot{тут токен}/sendPhoto
```

Comment: может быть у вас старая версия библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить `photo = FSInputFile("photo_2020-09-03_03-42-41.jpg")` на `photo = open('photo_2020-09-03_03-42-41.jpg', 'rb')`
Я не уверен что это поможет, но с **PyTelegramBotApi** я делаю только так.

Comment: Не работает так как метод message.answer_photo принимает строку или объект типа FSInputFile

Answer (score 0):

```
photo = InputFile("files/test.png")

await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
```

ИЛИ
вы можете отправлять фото по `file_id`

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def photo_handler(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer(msg.photo[-1].file_id)
```

просто отправьте боту фото и вы получите `file_id` фото

```
async def photo_handler(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer_photo(FILE_ID)
```